# jQuery datatables aaData not accepting array of Strings and works only with Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have tried to build a datatable using the datatables plugin.

Following are screen shots of the response I am getting using ajax in Firefox. For some reason I am not able to bind the data with the datatable in second scenario. The JSON object seems to be loading fine.

I have seen that in the first case I am sending back a list of Objects to the aaData variable for datatables and this works with the datatable. However in the second case where its not working, I am sending back the data in the form of string arrays in the json response for aaData. I cant send a list of java objects as I am not sure how many columns the table will have. It can have dynamic number of columns.

![Working Scenario][1]

![enter image description here][2]

I want to know what is going wrong in the second screen shot and why aaData is not accepting array objects?

Comment: Sorry images can be opened in a new tab. I am not sure why they appear to be so small on there. I am new to the site. many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by parsing the data using: 
`var json = JSON.parse(data);`